# Fill dictionary with lists

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists and 1 dictionary:

```
List<string> A;
List<string> B;
Dictionary<string, string> AB;
```

I would like to fill the dictionary with the 2 lists, where the value of each  member will be the name of the list where it comes from.

For example :
  `("from list A", "A")`
 `("from list A", "A")`
`("from list B", "B")`

The way I do it is long and I would like a more tricky solution:

```
 //Loop on A
  foreach (string item in A )
    {
        AB.Add(item, "A");
    }   

//Loop on B 
 foreach (string item in B )
     {
        AB.Add(item, "B");
     }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why that's so tricky about this solution and what are you looking for in a solution from us?

Comment: `"I would like a more tricky solution"` - Why on Earth would you like that?  "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." — Brian Kernighan

Comment: @GrawCube - no, that's just the same ingedients. Different cake though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use Linq:

```
var AB = A.Select(e => new { Key = e, Value = "A" }).Union(
         B.Select(e => new { Key = e, Value = "B" }) )
        .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

But it's not all that much shorter or clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks good enough the way it is!

If you seek to achieve shorter code, you could use the [List.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension
as in:

```
A.ForEach(x => AB.Add(x, "A"));
B.ForEach(x => AB.Add(x, "B"));
```

Oh and you might want to consider initializing the dictionary with the sum of the lists element counts.

Comment: Please explain the value of initializing the dictionary with a specified size in this instance. I see none.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 By initializing the dictonary with a specified size you assure that there won't be any resizing operations performed on .Add method. Please check  [Dictonary(Int32) constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @user4699981 that sure sounds like code clutter to solve a problem which doesn't exist.